# Tensorflow performance: Numpy matrix o TF matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_vars)
    cols = sess.run(tf.shape(descriptors)[1])
    descriptor_matrix = np.zeros((n_batches*batch_size, cols))
    while True:
        batch_descriptor = sess.run(descriptors, feed_dict={dropout_prob: 1})
        descriptor_matrix[i:i+elements_in_batch] = np.array(batch_descriptor)
```

I am mixing tensors and numpy vectors. Does this have an important impact on performance? Why is it? Should I just use tensors instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no problem mixing tensors and numpy.
But it is not good to perform processing outside "graph"(sess.run()).

Tensorflow/XLA compiler that makes "graph" in order to optimize performance.
graph is using when sess.run() is called.

But, Processing outside graph(sess.run()) is normal python code.
It does not benefit from XLA compiler.